# Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework

Help me understand why this isn't working:

```
Dim i = (From f In EfUtil.Db.EMAILADDRESSHISTORY _
                Where f.EMAILADDRESS.CUSTOMERCONTACTPERSON.CUSTOMERguid = New Guid(Request.QueryString("customer")) _
                Select New With {.guid = f.ACTIONguid, .name = f.ACTIONname}).ToList
```

I'm getting the following error

> Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ
>   to Entities.

Altough I'm finding a lot of examples where this construction works. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The examples you are finding most likely are LINQ to Objects examples and not LINQ to Entities.

You can work around this by declaring the GUID beforehand:

```
Dim customerGuid as Guid = New Guid(Request.QueryString("customer"))
Dim i = (From f In EfUtil.Db.EMAILADDRESSHISTORY _
         Where f.EMAILADDRESS.CUSTOMERCONTACTPERSON.CUSTOMERguid = customerGuid _
         Select New With {.guid = f.ACTIONguid, .name = f.ACTIONname}).ToList
```

To be clear: The problem here is not your `Select`. The problem is the `New Guid(...)` in the `Where` condition.

Comment: Like 'Select New customClass With {.guid = f.ACTIONguid, .name = f.ACTIONname}'?

Comment: @JurgenStillaert: What do you mean? My answer contains the code you should be using.

Comment: OK, that works. At first, there was no code example, that is why I did my first comment. Anyhow, any idea why I can't do new Guid("")?

Comment: @JurgenStillaert: You can't do that because LINQ to Entities doesn't actually execute the code you write there. It analyses the resulting Expression Trees and translates them to SQL.

Comment: Thanks. I could do new Guid("") in other queries, appearantly not when I want to instantiate anonymous classes. Good to know.

Comment: @JurgenStillaert: Believe me, this has nothing to do with the anonymous type. The queries where you were able to do this were no LINQ to Entities queries. If you have a concrete example from your code base I can tell you exactly why it works in that query.

Comment: EfUtil.Db.EMAILADDRESSHISTORY.Where(Function(f) f.ACTIONguid = New Guid(oSearchObject.newsletter)).Select(Function(f) f.EMAILADDRESSguid).ToList

Comment: @JurgenStillaert: Hm, that's interesting. I have to admit I don't see an obvious reason why this would work. What happens if you rewrite it to query syntax? `(From f in EfUtil.Db.EMAILADDRESSHISTORY Where f.ACTIONguid = New Guid(oSearchObject.newsletter) Select f.EMAILADDRESSguid).ToList`

Comment: It also works... But no matter what, it is good practice to declare the guid beforehand.

Comment: @JurgenStillaert: OK... Now, you can easily try to prove that you were right and I was wrong: Change `Select f.EMAILADDRESSguid` to `Select New With { .guid = f.EMAILADDRESSguid }`. If that doesn't work you were right in saying that the anonymous type is the reason why it doesn't work in the query of this question.